# Flutter: Widget for U shape

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[image: Visual graphic of the intended result]

I have been using flutter quite a while now but I have encountered a problem wherein I need to create a widget that would give me a shape in the form of U. I am trying to display the timeline of a user and the time he/she spent in the day doing different activities (represented by the colors in the shape). Can you suggest me a way to solve this problem and come up with a solution that allows me to control the length of the colored segment in the shape. Thanks!

I have tried using CustomPainter in flutter but I am not able to achieve what I intend to do.

Comment: CustomPainter is the correct way of doing this, but yeah, this might be pretty annoying to implement. You have to construct paths for every single color.

Answer (score 0):

Using CustomPainter, it's achievable. I have attached two screenshots, one is demo screenshot and other is explanation. Also the code is posted here and [dart pad link is shared](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f66106390cd0fec9c79b6cf904806060) too.

[image] [image]

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyActivity {
  String startTime;
  Duration duration;
  Color color;
  String title;
  Path path = Path();

  MyActivity({
    required this.startTime,
    required this.duration,
    required this.color,
    required this.title,
  });
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  final myActivities = <MyActivity>[
    MyActivity(
        startTime: "9 AM",
        duration: const Duration(hours: 1),
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(236, 33, 43, 1),
        title: "Activity A"),
    MyActivity(
        startTime: "10 AM",
        duration: const Duration(hours: 3, minutes: 30),
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(10, 162, 228, 1),
        title: "Activity B"),
    MyActivity(
        startTime: "1.30PM",
        duration: const Duration(hours: 2, minutes: 30),
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(40, 177, 84, 1),
        title: "Activity C"),
    MyActivity(
        startTime: "4 PM",
        duration: const Duration(hours: 3),
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(135, 4, 24, 1),
        title: "Activity D"),
    MyActivity(
        startTime: "7 PM",
        duration: const Duration(minutes: 30),
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(162, 74, 161, 1),
        title: "Activity E"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const inset = 24.0;
    final myActivityPainter = MyActivityPainter(myActivities: myActivities);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("Flutter Demo"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(inset),
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            child: CustomPaint(
              foregroundPainter: myActivityPainter,
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyActivityPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<MyActivity> myActivities;
  double strokeWidth = 0;
  double strokeWidthMidpoint = 0;
  double xStartPoint = 0;
  double yStartPoint = 0;
  double yBottomEndPoint = 0;
  double xEndPoint = 0;
  double distBetweenXPoints = 0;

  //doublerimeter of circle is 2*pi*r (our arc is semi-circle like)
  double radius = 0;
  double arcPerimeter = 0;
  double totalPerimeter = 0;
  Offset bottomCenter = const Offset(0, 0);

  MyActivityPainter({required this.myActivities});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _initializeFields(canvas, size);
    _initializeActivities(canvas, size);

    for (var element in myActivities) {
      var paint = Paint()
        ..color = element.color
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
      var path = element.path;
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

      var textStyle = const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 30,
      );
      var activityTextPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: element.title,
          style: textStyle,
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );
      var timeTextPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: element.startTime,
          style: textStyle,
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );
      var bounds = element.path.getBounds();
      activityTextPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: xEndPoint / 2);
      timeTextPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: xEndPoint / 2);
      var activityPos = Offset(
          bounds.centerRight.dx - activityTextPainter.width / 2,
          bounds.centerLeft.dy);
      var timeTextPos = Offset(strokeWidth, bounds.topRight.dy);
      // if the element is on the right side
      if (bounds.right > size.width / 2) {
        timeTextPos = Offset(
            bounds.right - timeTextPainter.size.width - strokeWidth / 2,
            bounds.topLeft.dy);
      }
      activityTextPainter.paint(canvas, activityPos);
      timeTextPainter.paint(canvas, timeTextPos);
    }
  }

  void _initializeFields(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    strokeWidth = size.width * 0.25;
    strokeWidthMidpoint = strokeWidth / 2;
    xStartPoint = strokeWidthMidpoint;
    yStartPoint = 0.0;
    xEndPoint = size.width - strokeWidthMidpoint;
    distBetweenXPoints =
        sqrt((xEndPoint - xStartPoint) * (xEndPoint - xStartPoint));
    radius = distBetweenXPoints / 2;
    yBottomEndPoint = size.height - radius - strokeWidth / 2;
    arcPerimeter = pi * radius;
    // left height + right height + bottom arc perimeter
    totalPerimeter = yBottomEndPoint * 2 + arcPerimeter;
    bottomCenter = Offset(size.width / 2, yBottomEndPoint);
  }

  void _initializeActivities(canvas, size) {
    final totalDuration = myActivities.fold(0,
        (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.duration.inMinutes);
    var consumedPerimeter = 0.0;
    var prevOffset = Offset(xStartPoint, yStartPoint);
    for (var element in myActivities) {
      final minutes = element.duration.inMinutes;
      if (minutes == 0) {
        continue;
      }
      element.path = Path();
      var path = element.path;
      var currPerimeter = (minutes / totalDuration) * totalPerimeter;
      // we cover left side, bottom(arc perimeter) and right side
      while (currPerimeter > 0 && consumedPerimeter < totalPerimeter) {
        if (consumedPerimeter >= yBottomEndPoint + arcPerimeter) {
          // this cover cases for right side height
          var availableHeight = totalPerimeter - consumedPerimeter;
          availableHeight = min(currPerimeter, availableHeight);
          path.moveTo(prevOffset.dx, prevOffset.dy);
          path.lineTo(xEndPoint, prevOffset.dy - availableHeight);
          prevOffset = Offset(xEndPoint, prevOffset.dy - availableHeight);
          consumedPerimeter += availableHeight;
          currPerimeter -= availableHeight;
        } else if (consumedPerimeter >= yBottomEndPoint) {
          // this covers bottom arc perimeter
          var availablePerimeter =
              (yBottomEndPoint + arcPerimeter) - consumedPerimeter;
          availablePerimeter = min(currPerimeter, availablePerimeter);
          path.moveTo(prevOffset.dx, prevOffset.dy);
          // distance between two points
          var arcPoint = findArcPoint(prevOffset.dx, prevOffset.dy,
              bottomCenter.dx, bottomCenter.dy, availablePerimeter, false);
          path.arcToPoint(arcPoint,
              radius: Radius.circular(radius), clockwise: false);
          prevOffset = Offset(arcPoint.dx, arcPoint.dy);
          consumedPerimeter += availablePerimeter;
          currPerimeter -= availablePerimeter;
        } else {
          // this cover cases for left side height
          var availableHeight =
              min(currPerimeter, yBottomEndPoint - consumedPerimeter);
          path.moveTo(prevOffset.dx, prevOffset.dy+1);
          path.lineTo(xStartPoint, consumedPerimeter + availableHeight);
          prevOffset = Offset(xStartPoint, consumedPerimeter + availableHeight);
          consumedPerimeter += availableHeight;
          currPerimeter -= availableHeight;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ref:- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275201/how-to-find-an-end-point-of-an-arc-given-another-end-point-radius-and-arc-dire
Offset findArcPoint(double aX, aY, cX, cY, L, bool clockwise) {
  var r = sqrt(pow(aX - cX, 2) + pow(aY - cY, 2));
  var angle = atan2(aY - cY, aX - cX);
  if (!clockwise) {
    angle = angle - L / r;
  } else {
    angle = angle + L / r;
  }
  var bX = cX + r * cos(angle);
  var bY = cY + r * sin(angle);
  return Offset(bX, bY);
}
```